# how can I use an if statement within a php variable?

Tags: php, html

I am using ajax to call a file on click of a 'card' to display a dialog box. It worked fine as normal html with php but now that I've saved it as a php variable it doesn't like the if statement and the drop downs always show the default 'choose' option. Can this be done? Or maybe I'm just writing it wrong?

```
$html.="<select name='priority'>";
$html.="<option>---Choose---</option>";
$html.="<option if ($priority == 'Low') echo 'selected' value='Low'>Low</option>";
$html.="<option if ($priority == 'Normal') echo 'selected' value='Normal'>Normal</option>";
$html.="<option if ($priority == 'High') echo 'selected' value='High'>High</option>";
$html.="<option if ($priority == 'Critical') echo 'selected' value='Critical'>Critical</option>";
$html.="</select>";
```

Answer (score 5):

It should be done like this:

```
$html .= "<option " .
         (($priority == 'Low') ? 'selected' : '') .
         " value='Low'>Low</option>";
```

Not using the Ternary operator:

```
$html .= "<option ";

if ($priority == 'Low') {
    $html .= 'selected';
}

$html .= " value='Low'>Low</option>";
```

Comment: Indeed, just concatenate the result instead of embedding it within a string.

Comment: For reference, he's using the Ternary operator: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: You might want to write that without the ternary as well – it's clear the person asking isn't well versed in this sort of thing.

Comment: Thank you, no not well versed at all, only starting dabbling

Answer (score 1):

You probably forget the difference. Everything you have in double quotes is a string. Try it with ternary:

```
        $priority = "Normal";
        $html = "";

        //Use from here
        $html .= "<select name='priority'>";
        $html.="<option>---Choose---</option>";
        $html.="<option ";
        $html.= (($priority == 'Low') ? 'selected' : '');
        $html.=" value='Low'>Low</option>";
        $html.="<option ";
        $html.=(($priority == 'Normal') ? 'selected' : '');
        $html.=" value='Normal'>Normal</option>";
        $html.="<option ";
        $html.=(($priority == 'High') ? 'selected' : '');
        $html.=" value='High'>High</option>";
        $html.="<option ";
        $html.=(($priority == 'Critical') ? 'selected' : '');
        $html.=" value='Critical'>Critical</option>";
        $html.="</select>";
        echo $html;
        exit;
```

Tested!